# Proof that All Entries in an Inverse Matrix are Integers

Tags: adjoint-operators, integers

"Prove that if $det(A)=1$ and all the entries in $A$ are integers, then all the entries in $A^{-1}$ are integers."

I began by setting up the adjoint method for finding the inverse.

$A^{-1} = \cfrac {1}{det(A)} adj(A)$

given that $det(A)=1$,

$A^{-1}=adj(A)$

At this point I'm stuck. I think I need to work with an example containing integers, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: So you need to show that the adjoint has integer entries. What were the entries of the adjoint again?

Comment: The coefficients in the adjugate are determinants of matrices with integer coefficients, being the algebraic complements.

Comment: They don't give one.

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient at place $(i,j)$ of $\operatorname{adj}A$ is the determinant of the matrix obtained by removing row $j$ and column $i$ from $A$, multiplied by $(-1)^{i+j}$.

The determinant of a matrix with integer coefficients is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rewording of the adjoint argument.

The inverse matrix is obtained by solving a matrix equation $AX=I$, which translates to $n$ linear systems. By Cramer's rule, the solution of each linear system has integer entries because $\det A=1$.

Answer (score 0):

For a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$, the adjoint $Adj(A)$ coincides with its matrix of cofactors, with (egreg refreshed my memory) a change of sign for the even entries, meaning those entries $a_{ij}$ with $i+j$ even.

And you can go further: an integer-valued matrix, i.e., a matrix with integer entries is invertible iff its determinant is $ \pm 1$: You know the determinant will be Integer-valued, and you need $Det(A)Det(A^{-1})=1$. So the determinant DetA will have to be a unit in the ring of integers , so that it must be $\pm 1$

Comment: $$Adj\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Yea, I mixed up the cofactor entries with the transpose. Just edited.